# Ionic reading data from SQLite during login in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

Im facing a problem reading the already set data from previous login after user abruptly switches from my App into another or restarts the phone. The data I've set after successful login does get saved in the SQLite database.

```js
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state,$http,ServerEndPoint,localStorageService,$cordovaGeolocation,$ionicActionSheet,dataShare,$ionicPush,loading,$rootScope,$cordovaSQLite) {
     
        $scope.data = {};
        
           //Does not work
           $scope.init = function()
           {
              $scope.load();
           };

           if(localStorageService.get("tradie_id") !== null && localStorageService.get("phone_no") !== null) {
            $state.go('menu.map');
           }
           
           //This is called from login form submit button click
           $scope.authenticateUser = function(loginForm){
                //Authenticating user from the server, after successful login
                //This one works
                $scope.addInfo(res.data.user_id,res.data.first_name,res.data.phone_no,status);
                
                $state.go('menu.map');
           }
  
  $scope.addInfo = function(user_id,first_name,phone_no,status){
    var query = "INSERT INTO user_data(user_id,first_name,phone_no,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[user_id,first_name,phone_no,status]);
    $scope.load();
  }
  
  $scope.load = function(){
    
    $scope.alldata = [];
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"SELECT * FROM user_data").then(function(result){
        if(result.rows.length)
        {
          for(var i=0;i<result.rows.length;i++)
          {
            $scope.alldata.push(result.rows.item(i));
          }
              
              localStorageService.set("user_id", $scope.alldata[0].tradie_id);
              localStorageService.set("first_name", $scope.alldata[0].first_name);
              localStorageService.set("phone_no", $scope.alldata[0].phone_no); 

        }else
        {
          console.log("No data found");
        }
    },function(error){
      console.log("error "+err);
    })
  }
           
})
```

Any suggestions or pointers to a sample source code is highly appreciated. I'm using ionic version 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't create or open the db when app ready first:

```
var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });
```